# Could we talk about affine spaces before vector spaces?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, vector-spaces, affine-geometry

I was recommended the book *Geometry* by Michele Audin by a professor when I asked about learning more about affine geometry.  I like the book, but it's raised a question.  To me, it seems that it would be nicer to lay down the foundation of geometry with affine geometry and *then* move on to geometry described by vector spaces.  But this is the opposite approach taken by the book.  This books builds up the concept of an affine space *from* the concept of a vector space.

Could we define an affine space without the concept of a vector space?  Is there a textbook which does this?  Thanks.